# Setting Boolean Preference default value depending on device langage (Locale)

Tags: android, default, locale, preference

I currently have an application where the french users should have a preference set to false by default and the other one should have this preference set to true.

I don't understand a correct and clean way to handle that.

Currently , in my app, I call 2 times the preference.

*) first time in my preference xml layout and in my preference activity, I have to set the preference at the first launch.

*) Second time, in my code:

```
boolean value = prefs.getBoolean("key"), true/false);
```

Thanbk a lot for all your ideas and explanations on how to make this in a clean way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use resources in such a way to accomplish this.

Folder structure (you can probably pick whatever name you want for the actual XML file or even create the resource with other resources):

```
/res/values/bools.xml
/res/values-fr/bools.xml
```

In `/res/values/bools.xml`:

- Make the boolean, you can rename this to whatever you need.

  - Name: pref_default
  - Type: boolean
  - Value: true

In `/res/values-fr/bools.xml`:

- Make the boolean again, same name

  - Name: pref_default
  - Type: boolean
  - Value: false

In your preferences.xml:

- Set the default value to @bool/pref_default

All set!

You should even be able to access that from code with `R.bool.pref_default`.

Disclaimer: I have never written code that involved multiple languages, but I have based this on my understanding of [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

If you mean the region France and not the French speakers, then you can probably find a `-r` qualifier for it (see my link).